# Textbox MaxLength for output

Tags: vb.net

How can I limit the max length of numbers that a textbox can display? For input Max Length from properties works, but not for output.

Comment: maxlength for textbox https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As I said, this works for input but not for output.

Comment: I think you're rather looking for a [**`NumericUpDown`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, without showing your code this is too broad.

Comment: I don't think NumericUpDown has anything to do with max length. There's no need for code, it's a textbox that displays calculation results and the maxlength works only for input that the user enters. I'm trying to limit digit number so it doesn't overflow.

Comment: @Jim Do you want to display, say, "OVERFLOW", if the number is too big? Otherwise, showing only part of a number will be showing the *wrong* number.

Comment: I want it to automatically limit the digit number displayed to 10

Comment: so for example if your result is "01234567890123456789" it will become -> "0123456789"

Comment: are you doing all of this with a button click?

Comment: no, its dynamic

Comment: Use the [**`TextChanged` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) then and truncate the text in there if it's too long.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to use truncate int he way that i want to. I don't want to hide decimals, I want to limit the number of digits.

Comment: YOU are the one putting the text into the TextBox. If you don't want it to display more than 10 digits then don't assign a `String` longer than 10 digits to the `Text` property. The reason that `MaxLength` only has an effect on text entered through the UI is because they think that a developer won't write code to display text longer than what they want displayed, so don't. Have you heard of an `If` statement? If the text you have is too long then shorten it. That's got nothing to do with the `TextBox`. Once it's been shortened, THEN display it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney what do you mean? I don't care what "they" think, I want the program to output the result with max 10 digits long. Is that so hard?

Comment: "I don't care what "they" think".  Really? You don't care what the creators of .NET and VB.NET intended when they created it?  That's probably not a good thing.  "Is that so hard".  No it's not, so why aren't you just doing it instead of expecting the `TextBox` to do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mentioned in the [`TextBox.MaxLength` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength) documentation:

> This property does not affect characters that are added programmatically.

It can be limited programmatically in various ways:

```
TextBox1.Text = Strings.Left(stringValue, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 1 line very simple. Check it out here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?850587-MaxLenght-Help&p=5193777&posted=1#post5193777